# What is incorrect with the following component in React.Component

Tags: reactjs, web-component

This is upwork test problem.
I can't guess answer at all.
Which answer is right?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        This is a component
        );
    }
}
```

Answers:

1. react render
2. react component
3. class should be replaced by className
4. render should not be a function

Comment: i think $40 an hour is a good rate for a tutor

Comment: The render doesn't return a html element, but just a flat string

Comment: So what is wrong?
I have only 4 options.
Which should I select?
Is it right render?
Is it right component?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you first read [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/). That should be a good start.

With regard to your question:

**1.** You can't return plain text inside render function, it needs to be wrapped inside an html tag. Thus your component should be something like :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>This is a component</div>);
    }
}
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/3134/)

Thus, `react render` isn't correct, because it returns nothing in your case.

And `class should be replaced by className` isn't correct. You use `className` instead of css `classes`.

Hope this helps. But I really suggest to read the docs first.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is : **React Render**

Because it is only returns a text whereas render function is supposed to return an element